# How to get the ACF Group Field value on corcel / acf?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on Laravel + Wordpress Project by using corcel. but I can't get the ACF group field value like the following.

```
use Corcel\Model\Page;

$homePage = Page::home()->first();
dd($homePage->acf->gig_category_section);
```

above output is null.
How can I get the ACF group field value by using corcel/acf?

Answer (score 1):

So far the documentation says about corcel, with it you will get the ability  to get the field value like this

```
$homePage->acf->field_name
```

Where, field_name refers to a single field. So, if you want to grab the group of all custom fields of that post, in that case, you can do that like this -

```
 $fields = get_field_objects($homepage->ID);

//This array is to keep the data here
$field_data = [];

foreach ($fields as $field_name => $data){
$field_data[$field_name] = $homepage->acf->field_name;
}
```

Now the data is available in $field_data.

Answer (score 0):

The group name becomes the field name prefix.

```
$homePage->acf->groupname_fieldname
```

Eg if my group is called buttons, and the field is called "button_one", the field becomes buttons_button_one

```
$homePage->acf->buttons_button_one
```